# Wordpress pagination and wp pagenavi plugins doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

i've made custom loop and I paginate results by 15 per page.
Seems doesn't work using wp_pagenavi plugins that paginate results by wordpress default (10 per page).
code here:

```
$p = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'books',
  'paged' => $p, 
  'post_per_page' => 15);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
   the_title();
   the_excerpt();
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi();
```

where I mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary that you passing parameters of your custom query on wp_pagenavi function.
Try this:

```
wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $query'));
```

read documentation: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/